# Click event on elements of Dynamically created Table in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my page, and on click it displays a dynamically created table. This is happening in a JS file.
Part of the table creation is as follows-

```
table_body = '<table border="1">';
    table_body += '<tr>';
        table_body += '<th>';
        table_body += '';
        table_body += '</th>';
        table_body += '<th>';
        table_body += 'Name';
        table_body += '</th>';
        table_body += '<th>';
        table_body += 'Age';
        table_body += '</th>';
    table_body += '</tr>';
    for(var i=0;i<number_of_rows;i++){
        table_body+='<tr>';
            table_body += '<td>';
            table_body += i+1;
            table_body += '</td>';
            table_body += '<td>';
            table_body += name[i];
            table_body += '</td>';
            table_body += '<td>';
            table_body += '<a href="" id='+name[i]+'>Age Action</a>';
            table_body += '</td>';
        table_body+='</tr>';
    }
    table_body+='</table>';
document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = table_body;
```

I am using Joomla Seblod and I have a div called **tableDiv**, and I'm replacing that div on the page with my created table after button click.
I'm not able to track clicks (and then do other stuff) on **Age Action** above, from the same JS file. On the same file I have-

```
jQuery("#55").click(newTestFunction); //I have a console.log in newTestFunction
```

id=55 in the first Age Action row. 
Is it because it's being dynamically generated? I have added the id attribute that should be different for different rows of it, but when I click on any one of them, it's not logging the console message that I have on click.

I also checked the page source and it does not show any of the elements of the table. How/where can I track any click on the  element? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use event delegation (i.e. `on()`) for dynamic content. Furthermore, you should not be mixing native JS with JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event must be after this line:

```
document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = table_body;
jQuery("#55").click(newTestFunction); //I have a console.log in newTestFunction
```

That way the "#55" element will exists when you add the event to it.

Comment: And I had it right at the top, in the beginning. Thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using doesn't match the Age Action link elements.

Try changing this line:

```
<a href="" id='+name[i]+'>Age Action</a>
```

...to this:

```
<a href="" id=name' + i + '>Age Action</a>
```

And prepending 'name' before the number in your selector:

```
jQuery("#name55")
```

Some things to note:

- An element id cannot start with a digit in valid HTML.
- This syntax: `name[i]` is actually an index into an array variable named 'name'

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments.